# Illustrator to Tagged PDF file

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Is there a way to save an Illustrator file to a Tagged PDF file.  I need to make the PDF 508 compliant and it would be faster if the conversion added the tags.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It verifies what I spent an hour trying to do! You would think that all the Adobe products would interact better. Oh well. Guess I'll have to tag the file the hard way!

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe so. There are many aspects of internal PDF data which Illustrator can't natively create, tags are one such item.